# Google Maps - zoom to fit markers doesn't work when map isn't visible

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I'm using the Google Maps API v2. I add markers to the map and then zoom to fit those markers. This works fine if the map is visible I do this. But if not - for example, if I have a tabstrip, and the map's tab isn't selected when the page loads - then when I do show the map, the zoom level and center are wrong.

Here's a simple test case (uses jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var scale = Math.random() * 20;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');
        // $container.hide();
        var map = new GMap2($('#map')[0]);
        $container.show();
        var markerBounds = new GLatLngBounds();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var randomPoint = new GLatLng(38.935394 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * scale, -77.061382 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * scale);
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(randomPoint));
            markerBounds.extend(randomPoint);
        }
        map.setCenter(markerBounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(markerBounds));
    });

</script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="map" style="margin: 100px; width: 450px; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

This works fine as is, but if you uncomment `$container.hide()` it's all whacked out.

Is there a way to get the Google Maps API to work properly on a div that's not visible?

Comment: `getBounds` (called in getBoundsZoomLevel) returns the visible area of the map, so I'd assume you would have to zoom to fit on the click event of the tabstrip.  The summary of the method in v3 is better than the description in v2: v3 "Returns the lat/lng bounds of the current viewport. If the map is not yet initialized (i.e. the mapType is still null), or center and zoom have not been set then the result is null."  I don't think getBounds has changed much between versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you would need to do is to create the `GMaps2()` before anything else. You can then `hide()` the container, add the points, get the `getBoundsZoomLevel()`, `show()` it again, and it should work fine.

Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $container = $('#container');

   // First create the Map.
   var map = new GMap2($('#map')[0]);

   // The container can be hidden immediately afterwards.
   $container.hide();

   // Now you can do whatever you like!
   var markerBounds = new GLatLngBounds();
   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var randomPoint = new GLatLng( 38.935394 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * scale, 
                                    -77.061382 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * scale);
      map.addOverlay(new GMarker(randomPoint));
      markerBounds.extend(randomPoint);
   }
   map.setCenter(markerBounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(markerBounds));

   // Finally unhide the container.
   $container.show();
});
```

[image: getBoundsZoomLevel]

Comment: You're right, that does work. The way my tabstrip works, though, is that everything is hidden on load (with CSS) and then the correct tab is displayed. Otherwise there would be a brief period in which all tabs are visible. So if it's at all possible I'd like to find a way to create the `GMap2` on a div while it's still hidden.

Comment: @Herb: Unfortunately it looks like the `GMap2` is not created properly with the mapping div set to `display: none`. If you search on google for "getBoundsZoomLevel returning 0" you will find some related stories. I think that your best bet is to work around this problem, by tweaking how your tabs work... I don't know if this may help, but if you hide the map with `$container.css('visibility', 'hidden');`, you can call `GMap2()` afterwards and it would work fine when you resume the visibility with `$container.css('visibility', 'visible');`.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. The `display:none` vs `visibility:hidden` distinction is interesting - not something I'd really understood before. It wouldn't work to use the visibility property to hide the tabs, since items with `visibility:hidden` still take up space on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've ended up doing, for what it's worth.

```
            $(".TabPanel").watch("display,visibility", function() {
                $(".MapContainer", this).each(function() {
                    if ($(this).is(":visible") == true) {
                        $(this).zoomToFitMarkers();
                    };
                });
            });
```

This uses [Rick Strahl's monitoring plugin for jQuery](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx) to watch the tab panel for visibility changes, and then reapplies the zoom logic.

For completeness here's my `zoomToFitMarkers` extension:

```
$.fn.zoomToFitMarkers = function() {
    var map = this[0];
    map.gmap.checkResize();
    map.bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
    if (!!map.gmap.getOverlays) {
        for (i = 0; i < map.gmap.getOverlays.length; i++) {
            map.bounds.extend(map.gmap.getOverlays[i].getLatLng());
        }
        if (map.bounds && !map.bounds.isEmpty()) {
            var zoomLevel = map.gmap.getBoundsZoomLevel(map.bounds);
            zoomLevel = zoomLevel > 9 ? 9 : zoomLevel;
            zoomLevel = zoomLevel < 2 ? 2 : zoomLevel;
            map.gmap.setCenter(map.bounds.getCenter(), zoomLevel);
        }
    }
    map.gmap.checkResize();
};
```

This relies on a couple of conventions:

1. The GMap2 object is stored in `map.gmap`, where `map` is the target DOM element:

   ```
   var map= $("div#MapTarget")[0];
   map.gmap = new google.maps.Map2(map);
   ```
2. Each time a marker is added to the map, it's stored in an array for future use:

   ```
   var marker = new GMarker(point);
   map.gmap.addOverlay(marker);
   // Keep track of new marker in getOverlays array
   if (!map.gmap.getOverlays) map.gmap.getOverlays = new Array();
   map.gmap.getOverlays.push(marker);
   ```